# Search keyword conflict in firefox

Tags: firefox, search, keyword

Where can I change the search keywords that I've added with "Add a Keyword for this Search..." ?

I've set "m" for google maps (which doesn't work by the way), and I'd like to change it to metacritic. Simply overriding or deleting the original google maps bookmark doesn't work.

The keywords are also not listed in: "Manage Search Engines".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage your Firefox 'search engines' in the bookmarks **library** located under `Firefox > Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks`.

[image: Bookmarks]

You can enable the `Keyword` column under `Views > Show Columns` for convenience.

[image: Keywords]

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the hint with the column view. The problem was that I had added google maps "m" twice and only deleted one of the entries.

Comment: Strangely this entry in the "Show Columns" menu appears to be gone in Firefox 64.