# Listing all Firefox keywords at the same time?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, keyword

This thread, [Search keyword conflict in firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/359934/search-keyword-conflict-in-firefox), illustrates how it possible to see what keywords your bookmarks have in Firefox.  However, when you select **Bookmarks** > **Show all bookmarks** and add the keyword column, you can only see the a sub selection of bookmarks at a time.  I want to see every single bookmark at the same time?  How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Easy:

I have discovered a trick! When you search within the **Firefox Bookmarks Library**, it will return a list of bookmarks that contain your sequence of characters in *any* of their fields. 99% percent* of bookmarks will contain a period in their **location**. If you search using `.`, it should list all of your bookmarks. If not, the **space** character seems to function as a wildcard.

After, you've listed all the bookmarks, click the **Keyword** tab to sort. :)

[image: bookmarks]

<sub>*I have a few bookmarks simply mapped to host names on my network.</sub>

### Hardcore:

Alternatively, you could export your bookmarks to HTML, and write a little program which scans the file, collecting keyword and bookmark pairings which are then sorted before printing the result. I was going to do this, until I played around with the search...

Comment: @glvzx tip is KISS! Works well with 8K bookmarks. And to display the `keywords` column since FF v40.0.2 [Mozilla devs removed both a bug and the ability to display keywords columns at the same time](https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/1077814#answer-767172), I used Palemoon which still supports it. Using both, I could review and edit a hundred clumsy keywords fields (ooold `Tags` dupes).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in 44 and possibly every version starting with 38.

Comment: There is no `keyword` in the columns for the bookmark search results anymore. Firefox 47 only offers tags, location, ... **Workaround:** Export all bookmarks as HTML, open this HTML file in your text editor, search for `SHORTCUTURL=` to find the existing keywords.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the "easy" method in [iglvzx's answer](https://superuser.com/a/385842/80810) no longer works. The "Keyword" column is missing from the list of choices, on modern FireFox builds.

See: https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Firefox/Firefox-library-keyword-column-missing/m-p/1140708 as well as the [bugzilla item](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145063)

Furthermore, on recent Firefox, they took away the ability of extensions to access profiles.sqlite, so the "SQLite Manager" option no longer works, either!

Firefox design is increasingly hostile towards keywords, sadly ):

Now, it seems the only good option to dump keywords is using the "hardcore" method from the other answer (dump to HTML) or edit the `places.sqlite` file directly, using `sqlite3` CLI or otherwise.

Note: if you go the `places.sqlite` route, you have to make sure to update the hash value of the URLs as well as the URLs themselves, if you are making changes. I've used this with success: [sqlite-mozilla-url-hash](https://github.com/bencaradocdavies/sqlite-mozilla-url-hash)

---

For reference, this seems to be the order of events:

1. **2015-03-19**: a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145063) is opened to remove the column. The reason seems to be that its presence was making some code migration difficult, and with some hand-waving, it was declared that the current UI was not good anyway, so it was okay to remove.
2. **2015-05-04**: the change is made to remove the column.
3. **2015-10-20**: people noticed the change, and started complaining. Response is "we will likely provide an alternative ui in the future".
4. **now**: The bug to track implementing a new UI is [648398](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648398), which is still open this many years later.

Answer (score 2):

Add a tag (i.e "KEYWORDS") as well as a keyword everytime you associate a keyword with a link.
Now click on Tags in the "Bookmarks Library" and find your links with the tag "KEYWORDS". 
Shizam! Wizadry!

Answer (score 2):

**Simplest Solution:**

In **bookmarks library**, **bookmarks sidebar** or **address bar** prepending `*`, search for `%%s`

**Explanation:** All keyword search bookmarks have a `%s` in their URL as placeholder for the search term.  In order to avoid finding literal `%` signs in the URL you have to escape it with another `%`.

Comment: This works as described in Firefox 102.6.0esr.

Answer (score 1):

I generate a list of keywords with a query in my SQLite manager from time to time, I need to open `<MyFirefoxProfileFolder>\places.sqlite` in my SQLite manager to run this query. https://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable / http://sqlitebrowser.org currently is my best choice of an sqlite manager because it's open source.

```
select moz_keywords.keyword, moz_places.title, moz_places.url, moz_keywords.post_data, moz_keywords.place_id from "moz_keywords" join "moz_places" on moz_keywords.place_id = moz_places.id order by moz_keywords.keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

I found somethings interesting for you in the *kb.mozillaZine.org*:

**Multiple parameter keyword searches**

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Multiple_parameter_keyword_searches

Hope this help. Let us know. :)

Comment: This is unrelated to the question here. `Multiple parameters` regards sending two inputs or queries, as opposed to one. Your link is about 'search engines' in Firefox, where a query replaces a variable in a URL.

Comment: Yes: you're right iglvzx :-/

Comment: Not strictly relevant but very interesting, thanks!