# How can I delete bookmarks when they are grouped according to tags?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

It would be convenient to be able to delete bookmarks when viewing them grouped by tag. But if you choose "Delete" from the context menu, Firefox just removes the relevant tag from that bookmark. To delete the actual bookmark I first search for it, delete it, and click on the tag again. Is there an easier way—a keyboard shortcut, an add-on, or a more efficient technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to *bookmarks* and show *all bookmarks*
2. in the *search windows* enter the tag your looking for
3. *left click* + *shift* and select select all
4. *right click*: **delete**

In this example I'm looking for "online tools"...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to show all bookmarks in a single view. I've discovered an easy way to achieve this here: [Listing all Firefox keywords at the same time?](https://superuser.com/q/385767/100787)

> When you search within the **Firefox Bookmarks Library**, it will
>   return a list of bookmarks that contain your sequence of characters in
>   *any* of their fields. 99% percent* of bookmarks will contain a period in their **location**. If you search using `.`, it should list all of
>   your bookmarks. If not, the **space** character seems to function as a
>   wildcard.
>
> [image: bookmarks]
>
> <sub>*I have a few bookmarks simply mapped to host names on my network.</sub>

Then, you can sort by **Tags** and manage your bookmarks from there. :)