# How to open all bookmark in firefox at once

Tags: firefox

How to open all bookmark in firefox at once in tabs including bookmark in all subfolder and bookmark toolbar?
I'm using firefox 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the folder in the Bookmarks menu or toolbar, and select *Open All in Tabs*.

If you literally want to open every single bookmark:

1. use Ctrl+Shift+B to open the Bookmark Library
2. type a space in the *Search Bookmarks* box
3. click on an item in the list below and use Ctrl+A to select all
4. right-click and select *Open All in Tabs*

[image: screenshot of Bookmark Library dialog]

You can also use this technique to get only certain types of bookmarks, such as those starting with `http:`, `ftp:`, or `file:`.

Comment: i mean all bookmark in all subfolders at once

Comment: doesn't work, in "Bookmarks Menu" the "Open All in Tabs." is greyed out

Comment: on the screenshot you clicked "Bookmarks Toolbar", but on the "Bookmarks Menu", the open all tabs option is disabled

Comment: also "Open All in Tabs" only open all bookmark within that folder, not subfolder

Comment: I've updated my answer; see if that helps.

Comment: @rob I recommend using `.` or even a space character to show all bookmarks. If you created a bookmark manually, you do not need to specify the protocol. See my answer here: http://superuser.com/a/385842/100787

Comment: @iglvzx: when I manually create a website bookmark (omitting `http://`), Firefox automatically adds `http://`. `.` can still miss items, such as files on the local filesystem which don't have a filename extension, but a space does seem to work, even for items that don't contain a space character in any of their fields. Thanks for the tip.